# How to override \today in a letter?

Tags: letters, date

Im trying to write a letter with the next code

```
\documentclass{letter}
\signature{Your name}
\address{Street \\ City \\ Country}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Company name \\ Street\\ City\\ Country}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam:}
\dots
\closing{Yours Faithfully,}
\ps{P.S. Here goes your ps.}
\encl{Enclosures.}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But I want to move the \today to the left above of company name and all that.
Or if this cant be moved simply to avoid it appears, but I don't want to mess the
letter.sty
Something more or less like this
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `\date{}` in the preamble and `\today\\\medskip` before "Company Name".

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{letter}
\signature{Your name}
\address{Street \\ City \\ Country}
\date{}
\begin{document}
 \begin{letter}{\today\\\medskip Company name \\ Street\\ City\\ Country}
  \opening{Dear Sir or Madam:}
  \dots
  \closing{Yours Faithfully,}
  \ps{P.S. Here goes your ps.}
  \encl{Enclosures.}
 \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The `\opening` is hard-coded within the class to add the date below the "from" address. While you can change it via `\date{<new date>}`, it will remain where it is set by the class. You can patch the location to be `\raggedright` (or flush left) instead of being part of the `tabular` "from" construction by adding the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\opening}% <cmd>
  {\@date\end{tabular}}% <search>
  {\end{tabular}\par\raggedright\@date\par}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

However, I'd suggest just setting the document, as a whole, using the standard `article` class. It'll allow you to have more freedom over the placement of content where you want it.

Here's a template you can use.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Remove paragraph indent

\begin{document}

\hfill
\begin{tabular}{ @{} l }
  Street \\
  City \\
  Country
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\today % Or whatever date you choose...

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{@{} l }
  Company name \\
  Street \\
  City \\
  Country
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Dear Sir or Madam:

\medskip

\dots

\medskip

\hspace*{.5\linewidth}%
\begin{tabular}{@{} l }
  Yours faithfully, \\[50pt]
  Your name
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

P.S.\ Here goes your ps.

\medskip

encl. Enclosures.

\end{document}
```